# Redirecting output to different path

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg

this is probably a quite easy question. I tried to solve it myself, looking at a whole bunch of different sites but couldn't find an answer.

Here it is: Change the variable "$output" so the output file of ffmpeg is written in a DIFFERENT directory than the current directory where the input files are.

Code is as follows:

```
$inputfiles = ls *.mxf

  foreach ($file in $inputfiles)
 
{$output = [io.path]::ChangeExtension($file, '.mp4')

  ffmpeg -i $file -map 0 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac $output}
```

Looking forward to your answers

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Have you tried updating the output path? put something like c:/Users/user/Desktop/test.mp4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just access the `BaseName` property of the files, this will allow you to *join* a path and setting the extension more very easy:

```
$inputfiles = ls *.mxf
$outputPath = 'D:\YOURPATH'

foreach ($file in $inputfiles) {
    $output = Join-Path $outputPath "$($file.BaseName).mp4"
    ffmpeg -i $file -map 0 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac $output
}
```